# Center two div's horizontally, next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I have two 's which I need to center horizontally but they need to be next to each other. Basically, the html that is added dynamically is a button. Here is my code for my two 's and the CSS is inline, I can't seem to get this working no matter what I try. If I use display: inline-block, I can't get them to be beside each other :(.

```
<div class="infor-experience col-lg-2 more_info">
  <div class="bottom-add-bid-buttons">
    {% if request.user|isEmployer %}
      <div class="add-to-list" style="float:left; width:300px;">{% include "layout/addtolistmodal.html" %}</div>
      <div class="connect-now bottom" style="width:300px; margin-left:320px;">{% include "layout/bidmodal.html" %}</div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

With this code, the two buttons are beside each other but they are not centered horizontally.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you just post your output screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed `float:left;` and reduced width by `150px` just for example. and gave `text-align:center` to parent and `display:inline-block` to child

```css
.bottom-add-bid-buttons {
  text-align: center
}
.add-to-list,
.connect-now {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="infor-experience col-lg-2 more_info">
  <div class="bottom-add-bid-buttons">
    <div class="add-to-list">div 1</div>
    <div class="connect-now bottom">div 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is something you could do with css flex box. 
All you need is mark *display:flex* and *justify-content: center;*

```css
.bottom-add-bid-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.bottom-add-bid-buttons > div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="infor-experience col-lg-2 more_info">
  <div class="bottom-add-bid-buttons">
    <div class="add-to-list">Some Text</div>
    <div class="connect-now bottom">Some other Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```